# sqlite-jdbc open database in Java code

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I try to open a database (YouTube.sqlite,    established by sqlite manager) in java code. The path should be ok; the driver is

```
   sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.1.jar.
```

But it does't work. When running, it shows 'Class.forName("org.sqlite.jdbc.Driver");' wrong.    Anyone can help me? Thanks.

```
    package mysqltest;

    import java.sql.Connection; 
    import java.sql.DriverManager; 
    import java.sql.ResultSet; 
    import java.sql.SQLException; 
    import java.sql.Statement; 
    import java.util.logging.Level; 
    import java.util.logging.Logger; 

    public class MySQLTest{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException {   

    String dbURL; 
    dbURL = "jdbc:sqlite://C://Users//13149//Desktop//YouTube.sqlite";

    Connection dbCon = null; 
    Statement stmt = null; 
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String query ="select * from CM";

    try { 
    //getting database connection to MySQL server
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.jdbc.Driver");
    dbCon = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);    

    //getting PreparedStatment to execute query
    stmt = dbCon.prepareStatement(query);

    //Resultset returned by query
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while(rs.next()){
    int count = rs.getInt(1); 
    System.out.println("count of stock : " + count);
    }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    //finally{
    //    dbCon.commit();
    //    //System.out.println("ex   ");
    //    }
    }  
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "shows it wrong"?

Comment: have you added `SqLite jdbc .jar` file to your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

The correct `Class.forName()` driver name for SQLite is

```java
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
```

but you should try simply omitting that statement altogether as it is not required unless you are running your code under a really old JDK/JVM (pre-JDBC_4.0).